# bash variable's if then statement not evaluating correctly

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have written a script that should tell me the number of lines from the nightly network backups. It should be 109 and if it is the same I get success email and if it is not the same I get a failure email. I have added 2 fake host to one of the files that is checked in the script below to see if it will fail. The if then statement simply does not work. If I make the amount of hosts in the file's 'confirm-backed-up' and 'backed-up' different it makes no difference and it just uses the very first if then statement regardless if they are different or not.

At the end you can see I ran the wc -l on the two files and they are different however the script runs and gives me the first then of the if, then: backed-up and confirm-backed-up match. It goes the other way also - if they are the same I just get the first if then statement - which at first made me think it was working until I checked it with the files not matching in number.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
date=`date +%Y%m%d`
o1=$(cat /netops/backups/scripts/hostfiles/backed-up | wc -l)
o2=$(cat /netops/backups/scripts/hostfiles/confirm-backed-up | wc -l)
sdir=/netops/backups/storage/
hostdir=/netops/backups/scripts/hostfiles
```

# Functions

```
function confirm_backup
{
find $sdir -type f -mtime 0 -printf '%f\n' |grep $date >$hostdir/backed-up
cat $hostdir/cisco-nexus.txt >> $hostdir/confirm-backed-up
cat $hostdir/cisco-firewall.txt >> $hostdir/confirm-backed-up
cat $hostdir/esx.txt >> $hostdir/confirm-backed-up
cat $hostdir/f5.txt >> $hostdir/confirm-backed-up
cat $hostdir/fortigate.txt >> $hostdir/confirm-backed-up
cat $hostdir/rsa.txt >> $hostdir/confirm-backed-up
cat $hostdir/sw-no-pk.txt >> $hostdir/confirm-backed-up
cat $hostdir/switch-router.txt >> $hostdir/confirm-backed-up
cat $hostdir/tlite.txt >> $hostdir/confirm-backed-up
}

# Verify Backup

function backup_verify
{
if [ "echo $o1" == "echo $o2" ]; then # I tried this with if [ "$o1" == "$o2"] also & if (( $o1 != $o2 )) & [ "$o1" = "o2" ] - all same results.
echo "backed-up and confirm-backed-up match" & mail -s "All Backups   succeeded" 12345566@blah.net   < /dev/null
else
echo "a backup has failed" & mail -s "A backup failed" 123456789@vtext.com  < /dev/null
fi
}

# Start Script Run

confirm_backup
backup_verify
cat /dev/null > $hostdir/confirm-backed-up # this is here for long term - i tested it with this gone so otherwise obviously my wc -l would have been 0
cat /dev/null > $hostdir/backed-up

user@host:/netops/backups/scripts$ ./test6.sh 
backed-up and confirm-backed-up match
Null message body; hope that's ok # WRONG!
user@host:/netops/backups/scripts$ cd hostfiles/
user@host:/netops/backups/scripts/hostfiles$ wc -l backed-up 
109 backed-up # so I check manually
user@host:/netops/backups/scripts/hostfiles$ wc -l confirm-backed-up 
111 confirm-backed-up # the files are different.
```

Comment: Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds. Among the issues -- `==` isn't guaranteed to work if you're actually being invoked with a shell other than bash; the comparison operator specified by the POSIX standard is `=`.

Comment: That said -- are you trying to compare two files, not two variables? You should be using `cmp` for that. And there's no point at all to having the string `echo` prefix both values.

Comment: Also -- use `bash -x yourscript` to run your script with each command logged. That way you can tell **exactly** what the values being tested against each other are.

Comment: Also, I'd strongly encourage you to build a [mcve] -- a reproducer with the smallest number of commands that reproduces the same problem if someone else copies-and-pastes it from your question (thus meaning that it doesn't depend on files, commands, etc. not widely available).

Comment: `if cmp -q file1 file2; then echo "Files are the same"; else echo "Files differ"; fi` will read only to the first point where the files differ, whereas if you're reading the files' contents into variables and comparing the variables, then the entire contents of both files need to be read (and if the files contain NULs, which can't be represented in shell variables, then your comparison will be incorrect).

Comment: I cant use cmp or diff because the file size is not what I am after. The output from that contains longer file names so the size of one file is much larger than the other. I was only after a number of lines in the file which without a longer grep/awk and more work it would take to try to get the files to match.

Comment: `diff` by the way, is very inefficient because it needs to calculate a textual description of exactly what the delta is -- it's always the wrong tool if you just want to know *if* things differ and not *how*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should set your variables **after** you populated your file `backed-up` and `confirm-backed-up`. Otherwise, the count of lines in the file is null, and the if condition is true (0 = 0).

So try changing this :

```
# Start Script Run

confirm_backup
backup_verify
cat /dev/null > $hostdir/confirm-backed-up # this is here for long term - i tested it with this gone so otherwise obviously my wc -l would have been 0
cat /dev/null > $hostdir/backed-up
```

To this :

```
# Start Script Run

confirm_backup
o1=$(wc -l < /netops/backups/scripts/hostfiles/backed-up)
o2=$(wc -l < /netops/backups/scripts/hostfiles/confirm-backed-up)
backup_verify
cat /dev/null > "$hostdir"/confirm-backed-up # this is here for long term - i tested it with this gone so otherwise obviously my wc -l would have been 0
cat /dev/null > "$hostdir"/backed-up
```

Also, for numeric comparison, use `-eq` and get rid of the `echo`:

```
if [ "$o1" -eq "$o2" ]; then
    # do stuff
fi
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Should still quote even on numeric comparisons -- if `IFS=0`, then `$o1` can expand wrong. And if your intent is to demonstrate correct code, you should **definitely** be quoting all the directory-name expansions.

Comment: And btw, `wc -l </filename` is significantly more efficient than `cat filename | wc -l`; that's even more so in the case of `wc -c`, which is constant-time with a real file descriptor (since it can use either `fstat()` or `seek()` and `tell()` to get the total length of the file immediately) but O(n) with the length of a file when given a pipeline from `cat` (in which case it has to actually read the whole stream and count bytes).

Comment: That is the ticket - thanks. I kept having issues with the script giving me errors when the two files in those variables did not exist. I just thought I had to run my variables at the top and kept wondering why it was trying to process them before my script called them. I am just learning bash and scripting so thanks.

Comment: I was wondering why this might not work: I had two mail variables and my script simply runs them immediatly:  mailfail=$(mail -s "A backup failed" 123456778@vtext.com < /dev/null)
mailsucceed=$(mail -s "All Backups Suceeded" 123456789@vtext.com < /dev/null)

Comment: @AlexTomko, there you're capturing the *output* (to stdout) of the `mail` command. Does it actually _have_ any useful output at all? I wouldn't expect so, so I wouldn't expect those commands to be useful. If you want to do is store the command for later invocation, then see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). If you want to store text of any error messages (ie. if the mail couldn't be sent), then you need to redirect stderr.

Comment: @AlexTomko, ...so, yes, running them immediately is exactly what those commands are supposed to do. If you want to define code to run later, consider a function: `mailsucceed() { mail -s "All Backups Suceeded" 123456789@vtext.com < /dev/null; }`, after which you can just run `mailsucceed`.

Comment: So like this: `mailsucceed() 
{ mail -s "All Backups Suceeded" 123456789@vtext.com < /dev/null; } `
`mailfail() 
{ mail -s "All Backups Suceeded" 123456789@vtext.com < /dev/null; } `
# Verify Backup
`function backup_verify
{
if [ $o1 -eq $o2 ]; then
    echo "backed-up and confirm-backed-up match" & mailsucceed
else
echo "a backup has failed" & mailfail

fi
} `

Comment: I have to output to stdout for the mail because otherwise it hangs the mail - the mail is looking for a text body so it sits forever unless you do the output - or if i specified a mail body it would be fine but it hangs without the output to /dev/null